# Trying to extract the text in specific cell in pandas

Tags: python

I have dataframe which contains  5 columns.

```
Ex : A B C D E F
```

at  F name Column, data consists like below

```
  F
Name:
Age:
Gender:
Class:
City:
State:
```

Now I want extract the text/data from F Column like below.

```
  F
Name:
Age:
City:
State:
```

Please suggest me any patterns or soultions

Comment: Have a look in [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), also try to understand the role of indices and columns.

Comment: the cells of F column are multi-line strings ?

Comment: yes, a cell contains multiple values.

Comment: @mkk assuming `df` your DataFrame, please [edit] the question with the output of `df.to_dict('tight')` to form a [mre].